# Placing a box around centered text in Ruby

Tags: ruby

This is a super basic ruby question. Just learning ruby and I'm trying to build out a box where it finds the longest word in the string and makes the box that width with spaces on either side and then centers all the other text i've passed in.

so far i have this;

```
def box(str)
arr = str.split
wordlength = arr.max_by(&:length).length 
width = wordlength + 4

width.times{print "*"}
puts "\n"
arr.each {|i| puts "* #{i} *" }
width.times{print "*"}
end
```

but the above prints out:

```
***********
* texting *
* stuff *
* test *
* text *
***********
```

i'd like it to print something like the below

```
***********
* texting *
*  stuff  *
*  test   *
*  text   *
***********
```

thanks

Comment: Step 1: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/String.html Step 2: Ctrl-F center

Comment: Also, you can do this: `puts "*" * width` to make the code a little more concise if you want.

Comment: that makes sense think i was working something else and just left it that way. thanks keith

Answer (score 0):

Here, this code works:

```
def box(str)
  arr = str.split
  wordlength = arr.max_by(&:length).length
  width = wordlength + 4

  width.times{print "*"}
  puts "\n"
  arr.each do |i|
    current_length = i.length
    puts "* #{fill_space(current_length, wordlength, 'pre', i)}#{i}#{fill_space(current_length, wordlength, 'post')} *"
  end
  width.times{print "*"}
end

def fill_space(current_length, max_length, where, current='')
  spaces_to_fill = max_length - current_length
  if where == 'pre'
    str = ' ' * (spaces_to_fill / 2)
  elsif spaces_to_fill % 2 > 0
    str = ' ' * (spaces_to_fill / 2 + 1)
  else
    str = ' ' * (spaces_to_fill / 2)
  end
end
```

The problem was,that you didn't calculate how many " " you should insert into your current row. In the fill_space function I calculate exactly that, and I call this function for each row that should be printed. Also, if there are odd words this function adds the additional space in the end of the row.
I didn't change much of your box function but feel free to insert the hint that Keith gave you

Comment: Still have problems?